# Compute $\int_C \frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2}}dz$ where $C$ is the curve $\gamma(t)=(-2\sin t,2\cos t,2t^2)$ for $t\in[0,1]$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Compute $\int_C \frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2}}dz$ where $C$ is the curve $\gamma(t)=(-2\sin t,2\cos t,2t^2)$ for $t\in[0,1]$

So to find the integral of this function I believe I take:
$$\int_{U^{int}} f\circ\gamma \text{Vol}(D\gamma)$$

$\gamma^\prime(t)=(-2\cos t,-2\sin t,4t)$

Where $\text{Vol}(D\gamma)=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^3 \gamma_i^2}=\sqrt{4\cos^2 t+4\sin^2t+16t^2}=\sqrt{4+16t^2}=2\sqrt{1+4t^2}$

and $f\circ\gamma(t)=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$

But this integral I find $\int_0^1 \frac{2\sqrt{1+4t^2}}{1+t^2}dt$ I am not able to compute and when I've tried using an integral calculator its not able to compute it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The vector field

$$\vec{F}(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2}}\vec{k}$$

(where $\vec{k}=(0,0,1)$) is the gradient of the function

$$f(x,y,z)=2\log \left(1+\frac{z}{2}\right).$$

Comment: So I have $\nabla f=(0,0,\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2}})$ and then $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=(0,0,\frac{1}{(1+\frac{z}{2})^2}$ which gives me $\int_C \langle F,T\rangle=\int_0^1 \frac{4t}{(1+t^2)^2}dt$. Then using $u=1+t^2$ gives $\int_0^1 \frac{2}{u^2}du=-2(1+t^2)\big\vert_0^1=1$

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are the end points of $\gamma$, then $\int_\gamma \vec{F} =\int_\gamma \nabla f=f(b)-f(a)$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Oh I see what you meant $F$ is a gradient field. Is there a way to solve this using integration over the curve using the definition for integration over manifolds?